# Read second key value from dictionary

Tags: python

I have data like this - 
How to read and print the data like below using python

```
data = [{u'week_id': u'201653', u'team_id': 158}, {u'week_id':u'201627', u'team_id': 221}]
packets = tuple(x["team_id"] for x in oracle_partitions)
print packets
output - [158,221]
```

wanted output -

```
[{'team_id': 158}, 'team_id': 221}, .....]
```

but its only printing the values like

```
[{158}, {221}....]
```

Comment: You won't get the output you mentioned, you will get `(158, 221)`, please fix your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension with a dictionary as the value:

```
data = [{u'week_id': u'201653', u'team_id': 158}, {u'week_id':u'201627', u'team_id': 221}]
packets = [{"team_id": x["team_id"]} for x in data]
print packets
```

Output:

```
[{'team_id': 158}, {'team_id': 221}]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for . But now once I identified the team_id's how to print week_id and team_id for that team_id  . Let me post it as a question

Answer (score 0):

```js
data1 = [{u'week_id': u'201653', u'team_id': 158}, {u'week_id':u'201627', u'team_id': 221}] 
data2 =[{'team_id':221}] 
partitions = [partition for partition in [{"team_id": x["team_id"]} for x in data1] if partition not in data2] 
print partitions 
Gives me a result {'team_id': 158}
But I want to print the whole tuple set {u'week_id': u'201653', u'team_id': 158} ...
```

data1 = [{u'week_id': u'201653', u'team_id': 158}, {u'week_id':u'201627', u'team_id': 221}] 
data2 =[{'team_id':221}] 
partitions = [partition for partition in [{"team_id": x["team_id"]} for x in data1] if partition not in data2] 
print partitions 
Gives me a result {'team_id': 158}
But I want to print the whole tuple set {u'week_id': u'201653', u'team_id': 158}